# How to run a bat file in apache server using Rotatelogs configuration ?

Tags: apache, logging, httpd.conf, apache2.4

I am trying to rotate the log file in apache server. I tried a lot using rotatelog configuration in httpd.conf in apache configuration. But I can't.

while i configuring the rotatelog in httpd.conf, i found that `Rotatelog` having the option to run a program that can be acheived by using parameter `-p`. So i wrote a bat file to rotate the logs. And configured with apache server like below command

```
ErrorLog "|bin/rotatelogs.exe -l -p logs/apachelog.bat errorlogs 1M"
```

Whether My way of configuration is correct or not. Once error log file reached that particular file size , i want to execute the bat file. So i tried like this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which apache version are you using?

Comment: Can you show the `apachelog.bat` file?

Comment: `NET STOP "WebServer"`
`del error.log`
`echo 2>error.log`
`NET START "WebServer"`

Comment: Shouldn't the commands work on `errorlogs` file?

Comment: Am not sure about that command. i just tried. i want to run that bat file once errorlog file reached some size. `errorlogs` is file given by me to write some logs after reaching particular size.

Comment: What do you observe?